# react-native run-ios takes forever to build and sometimes never does

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, native

I start my app with react-native run-ios and i get left at this portion of the build process, sometimes indefinitely. why does this happen?

Alexs-MBP:swig_app alexhome$ react-native run-ios
Found Xcode project swig_app.xcodeproj
Building using "xcodebuild -project swig_app.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme swig_app -destination id=C46C9065-C23A-4118-AB00-5957B64086B1 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:

```
IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/alexhome/Desktop/swig_app/ios/build
```

Ive tried all the usual cleaning commands such as watchman watch-del-all and virtuall ever other cache cleaning command there is. sometimes the make it worse tho

package.Json:

{
  "name": "swig_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation happen to me recently after I deleted the build file in the IOS folder. I ran react-native run-ios and it was stuck in the same place forever. I then tried opening the project in Xcode and realized Xcode was not opening the project at all and so react-native could not build the project. I restarted my computer, tried opening the project again in Xcode and when that worked, I closed it and ran react-native run-ios and everything went back to normal.

Comment: Whenever my build gets stuck, rather than restarting, I just kill all of my Node processes.

Answer (score 3):

run `killall -9 node` to kill the all node processes.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens on first build, so simple resolution is to quit the running process and then delete the ios/build directory after that rerun the command "react-native run-ios" again.

For more information refer to this thread

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24815

May be this helps you or somebody else, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sequence that worked for me:

1. Uninstalling the app from the simulator.
2. Restarting the system